# access denied in R

Tags: r, windows

I have an issue with R I can't solve.
When I open R, I have the following error message:

```
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="//serverFPR/Redir/FPR/Trantsyx/My Documents/R/win-library/3.2": Access is denied
```

This problem appeared from nowhere. And since, whatever I do, I have the same message, so I can't install a package, call a library and consequently, I can't use any function from the packages.
I rebooted the computer, uninstalled and reinstalled R three times, checked if the folders are not "Read only"... Nothing work, I still have this problem and I have no idea how to solve it.

I have seen on stackoverflow some issue with that, but it was about package building, which is not my issue...

Help, please.
Thank you very much!

Comment: as admin or as normal user or restricted user. Which rights you had during the actions?

Comment: As normal user. When I open R by clicking right "Use as administrator", I have the same message. it is on the University server, but I didn't have any issue until now, and i am apparently the only one in my office with this problem